# SSRS parameter search by Member ID

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

I'd like to build a SSRS report that has an parameter set to filter by member number. I have a basic query here:

```html
SELECT * FROM CN_RV_Customer_Notes
```

I'm not sure if I need an additional query. I need the report to display all results & the ability to filter by customernumber (column result from query.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, it will take a few steps.

First, add a new dataset that retrieves the distinct memeber numbers so you can use this later. Call it param_ds_membernum or something.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(MemNumCol) AS MemNum
 FROM CN_RV_Customer_Notes
```

Make sure the dataset is in Report Data pane, if you made it in the Solution Explorer you will need to add a shared datasource.

Next, right click on the Parameters folder in the Report Data pane. Then Add Parameter.  Fill in the Parameter name and prompt. If you want to be able to select multiple members select Allow Multiple Values, if not leave it.  Prompt is just what the user will see when changing the member. The Name is most important, lets call it @MemberNumber. In Available values, Hit get Values from Query, then select param_ds_membernum for Dataset. For Value select the only option MemNum. Same for Label field. For Default Values, just do the same thing as Available.

Then, you will need to add the parameter in the main data set:

```
SELECT *
FROM CN_RV_Customer_Notes
WHERE MemberNumber IN (@MemberNumber)
```

Change the WHERE MemberNumber to whatever the member number column name is.

Last, right click on the main data set in the Report Data pane, go to Parameters, click Add. Use the dropdown to add @MemberNumber to the value and @MemberNumber to the name.

You should be good.

Comment: That worked great! Thanks.. If i wanted to add that same parameter to a stored procedure, would it work the same way?

Comment: Yup, you can use a stored proc parameter too. Just make sure when setting up the Dataset and Datasource in the report data that under the Parameter tab you link the right parameters to the value.